# Laravel - Data mismatch from eager load

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I am creating factories and saving the `page` model to the `film` model so its film to page one-to-many,

i've followed the docs but when im trying to save the models to each other i am getting this error

```
 General error: 20 datatype mismatch (SQL: insert into "pages" ("id", "page_url", "film_id", "updated_at", "created_at") values (591d61cb-3090-3945-b920-ba797245cb97, http://larson.com/, bd3bab38-f8be-4674-ae5d-15e8f6b6172a, 2019-11-15 11:23:02, 2019-11-15 11:23:02))
```

These are the classes i am working with

**`Film migration`**

```
 public function up()
{
    Schema::create('films', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->uuid('id')->primary();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('description');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

**`Pages migration`**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('pages', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->uuid('film_id')->nullable();
        $table->string('page_url')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

**`PagesFactory`**

```
$factory->define(Pages::class, function (Faker $faker) {
return [
    'id' => $faker->uuid,
    'page_url' => $faker->url,
    'film_id' => factory(\App\Models\Film::class)->create()->id
];
```

**`Pages model`**

```
public function film(): BelongsTo
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Film::class);
}
```

**`FilmController`**

```
  */
public function show(string $id)
{
    $film = Film::with([
        'pages',
        'languages',
        'categories',
    ])->findOrFail($id);

    return $film;
```

**`FilmControllerTest`**

```
public function getFilmTest()
{
        $film = factory(Film::class)->create();

        $language = Language::where('id', 'en')->where('name', 'English')->first();
        $categories = Category::where('main-cat', 'Science')->where('sub-cat', 'Fiction')->first();

        $film->pages()->save(factory(Page::class)->create());

        $film->languages()->attach($language->id);
        $film->categories()->attach($categories->id);

        $response = $this->json('GET', '/film/' . $film->id)
            ->assertStatus(200);

        $response
            ->assertJson(['id' => $guestProfile->id])
            ->assertJson(['name' => $film->description])
            ->assertJson(['languages' => $film->languages->toArray()])
            ->assertJson(['categories' => $film->categories->toArray()])
    }
```

when i comment out this line from the test it works fine `$film->pages()->save(factory(Page::class)->create());`

im abit lost on why im having this issue trying to save the models so the pages becomes part of the response... can i get some help/example please :D

Comment: Are you using local database to test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `id` of your `pages` table is set to a `bigIncrements` (`UNSIGNED BIGINT`), but in your `PagesFactory` you are trying to store a `uuid`.

```
$factory->define(Pages::class, function (Faker $faker) {
return [
    'id' => $faker->uuid,
    'page_url' => $faker->url,
    'film_id' => factory(\App\Models\Film::class)->create()->id
];
```

Remove `'id' => $faker->uuid,` from the factory, you don't have to set an auto incrementing field.

Another option (depending on the design you have in mind) is to change the migration of the `pages` table and set the `id` column to `$table->uuid('id')->primary();`

Answer (score 0):

try using the make() method, as in:

```
$film->pages()->save(factory(Page::class)->make());
```